# Runtime class is returnig java used haep space as zero(0)

Tags: java, heap-memory

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Used Memory:" + (runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory()) / mb);

Outputi i am getting is zero every time,but i have two process running on.

Comment: So what's the question then?!

Comment: What is `mb`? Maybe you're doing integer division and you're using less than 1 MB?

Comment: Thanks Jesper I got it thats the problem